# Overloading a method in an ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overloading, activesupport

How can I have a concern that I've written like this:

```
module Concerns
  module MyConcern
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    ...
    def my_concern_magic(arg0,arg1)
      #exciting stuff here
    end
  end 
end
```

that is included in a model that overloads `my_concern_magic`? E.g.

```
class User
  include Concerns::MyConcern
  ...
  def my_concern_magic(arg0)
    arg1 = [1,2,3]
    my_concern_magic(arg0,arg1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since including a module inserts it into the ancestor chain, you can just call `super`:

```
class User
  include Concerns::MyConcern

  def my_concern_magic(arg0)
    arg1 = [1, 2, 3]
    super(arg0, arg1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Worked like a charm.